# How much shifts the Subtropical high zone from 30 degrees during seasons?

Tags: climate

The Intertropical Convergence Zone (ITCZ) is a band of low pressure that runs around the planet Earth; The Polar front is the Arctic band of low pressure that run around 60° N and south.

Both those bands are subject to shifts and deformation due to the thermal differences and pressures and mostly are afected by the shape of the land they encounter.

The Subtropical High Zone (STHZ) instead is the correspondent high pressure area that runs around 30 degrees north and south in general between the other two types of bands.

The ITCZ is frequently bent due to pressure differences between highs;Likely so does the Polar front, but the behaviour of the STHZ... is what I'm trying to understand.

How does the STHZ deform according to the changes on the polar front and ITCZ during the seasons, if it does at all?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Living at 29.5° north latitude, I can answer with some assuredness that the subtropical high shifts in latitude over the course of a year. Some of the year we get winds that are from the east, other times from the west, and yet other times, none whatsoever (horse latitudes). That however is personal experience. I'm not at all sure of the magnitude of that shift, or whether it is worldwide.

Comment: winds on terrain can change due to orography so it can be more erratic, unless you live on the coast and flat land?